# div::after with position:fixed breaks site

Tags: javascript, html, css

[reposting deleted question with more detail]
I've searched for an answer to this but not found a reference to anything similar. This is a minimal version of the HTML / CSS / Javascript:

```js
function switchitem(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.className.indexOf("item-wrap-hidden") != -1) {
    x.className = "item-wrap";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace("item-wrap", "item-wrap-hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

.item-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.item-wrap-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="switchitem('id')" class="accordion">Show / Hide Content</button>
<div id="id" class="item-wrap-hidden">
  <p>content that is hidden and revealed goes here</p>
</div>
```

Which works exactly as desired: the button is onscreen, when button is clicked the item-wrap box appears, when button is clicked again the item-wrap box disappears. In the production version, there's some styling and CSS animation.

I then went on to style the item-wrap box so its background is a blurred lower-opacity version of the body background image, which broke the functionality. Non-working minimal version:

```js
function switchitem(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.className.indexOf("item-wrap-hidden") != -1) {
    x.className = "item-wrap";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace("item-wrap", "item-wrap-hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

.item-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.item-wrap::after {
  overflow: hidden;
  content: "";
  background-image: url("page_background_image.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .8;
  filter: alpha(40);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.item-wrap-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="switchitem('id')" class="accordion">Show / Hide Content</button>
<div id="id" class="item-wrap-hidden">
  <p>content that is hidden and revealed goes here</p>
</div>
```

Adding this deactivates the button once the content is revealed, so it can't be hidden again. On my production page, there are multiple accordion folds, and it deactivates the buttons for all of them, so once you've unhidden one fold you can't do anything else.

Changing the position property of `item-wrap::after` to `absolute`  makes the page work as desired, but testing in Chrome and Safari on Mac there are lots of artifacts, and the page becomes twitchy, slower and less responsive. Here are linked examples:

[Working Production Example](https://www.thesadsongco.com/frank/index.php?stats=true) - when the content is animated in the blurred image behind jitters, and the page is noticeably less responsive when scrolling

[Broken Example](https://www.thesadsongco.com/frank/stack_index.php) - when any button is clicked to reveal content it deactivates all the rest of the buttons on the page. However, the background image doesn't jitter behind the animation on my machine, and the page doesn't become less responsive.

I am happy with my workaround (it's not a commercial project so the twitchiness is not an issue), but I am very curious as to why the position: property is affecting the functionality in this way. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `::after` is over the whole screen, so you're clicking it and not the button. Button is "under" the `::after`. You can see that by removing opacity.

You can add

```
pointer-events:none;
```

to the `::after`, so you're actually clicking the button.

Comment: I will need to research why `position: absolute;` doesn't have the same effect. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Position absolute on what element?

Comment: On the `item-wrap::after` element. That's how I solved the problem, but I didn't fully understand why. Now I have a bit more of a basis to research why and learn some more.

Answer (score 2):

your button is blocked by the position: fixed pseudo element, give it position: relative and z-index to move it up

```js
function switchitem(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.className.indexOf("item-wrap-hidden") != -1) {
    x.className = "item-wrap";
  } else {
    x.className = x.className.replace("item-wrap", "item-wrap-hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

.item-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.item-wrap::after {
  overflow: hidden;
  content: "";
  background-image: url("page_background_image.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .8;
  filter: alpha(40);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.item-wrap-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="switchitem('id')" class="accordion">Show / Hide Content</button>
<div id="id" class="item-wrap-hidden">
  <p>content that is hidden and revealed goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: add a z index as well to the button

Comment: That sorts out the button problem, but means the styling effect (blurred background image behind div) doesn't work. See [link](https://www.thesadsongco.com/frank/stack_index2.php) for example with position: relative and z-index: 5